# Creating a new DefinitelyTyped definition

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I've created a new Typescript definition that I'd like to test before adding it to DefinitelyTyped. When I try to install the definition from a local file, I receive the error:

```
 Unable to find "myfile.d.ts" ("npm") in the registry.
```

Is it required that I create an entry in the registry before testing my file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try to install the definition from a local file, I receive the error

Don't install it locally. You just create a `-test` file that references your file and uses it as a module. e.g. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/084e55916674ff7128722bf72150aa55acea08d9/FileSaver/FileSaver-tests.ts#L3